# padding-left applied to multiple react pages?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a sidebar, and a page (home.component.js) to the right of this sidebar.

To make the content not fall behind the sidebar, I have included a padding left of 20vw in the body of my index.css

[image]

```
  background: #f0f0f0 !important;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  padding-left: 20vw;
}
```

However, this is casing the same padding to appear on my sign up form, featured below

[image]

Code for sign-up page is below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import TopNav from "./TopNav"
export default class SignUp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <navbar>
<TopNav />
          </navbar>,
                <div className="auth-wrapper">
                <div className="auth-inner">
            <form>
              
            <h4>Sign Up</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
            </p>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>First name</label>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First name" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Last name</label>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Last name" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Email address</label>
              <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
            </div>
            <p classname="forgot-password text-right">
              Already registered <a href="/sign-in">log in?</a>
            </p>
            <button type="submit" className="button">Sign Up</button>
          
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I make this padding only appear on my homepage, and not carry forward to my Sign Up page, so the sign up page has no padding-left?

Homepage

```
    render() {
        return (
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>

               <Sidebar />

  
                 <h1>Right of sidebar page </h1>
            </div>

        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of hard coding a left padding, have you considered using flexbox and simply dynamically rendering the sidebar on some pages (which you already do?). Then the layout is automatically handled by the browser, without you needing to manually toggle the padding on/off.

Comment: Can you provide an example as to how I should adjust my code? @Terry

Comment: If I am rendering the sidebar only on the pages already, how can I change my homepage so that the right hand content does not fall behind the sidebar? @Terry

Comment: @Terry and I am already using flexbox?

Comment: But the way you're using it is unclear: you only showed the layout for the homepage. Ideally the "app" should have a flexbox layout: the div will have two children: one for a conditionally rendered sidebar, and another for whatever content that should be rendered on the page.